# Get function argument type on function declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm building a custom React hook which accepts an object (which has a function as one of the properties) as argument.

I want to get type definition on that function's arguments, which I am currently able to do like this:

```
  const { submitHandler, register } = useForm({
    handleSubmit: data => {
      /*
      Everything is ok:
      (parameter) data: {
          inputs: InputRefs;
          e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;
      }
      */
    }
  });
```

However, I'd like to split the code by getting `handleSubmit` outside the `useForm` argument object like so:

```
  const handleSubmit = data => {
    // Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.
  };

  const { submitHandler, register } = useForm({ handleSubmit });
```

But if I do this, `data` is of type "any"... Is there a way to get the type definition for that function's arguments? Or the only and correct solution is really just export/import the type?

Sorry if this is not explicit or has already been explained, but I just started learning typescript and I can't seem to find what are the correct keywords to find the answer to what I am asking...

Thank you

Comment: If you have interface of your data for handleSumbit (which you probably do) you should specify it in function ```const handleSubmit = (data: SubmitValuesInterface) => {}```. This should let you pass this function into useForm hook

Comment: Is `useForm` the one from https://react-hook-form.com/?

Comment: Well it's not react-hook-form but it's basically me copying it just to learn something...

Comment: @VasylButov yeah, I just wanted to try to avoid the need to import that Interface in every file I use my custom hook... But ye, if there's no other choice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on `handleSubmit` here:

```
const { submitHandler, register } = useForm({
    handleSubmit: data => {
      /*
      Everything is ok:
      (parameter) data: {
          inputs: InputRefs;
          e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;
      }
      */
    }
  });
```

and choose "Go to Definition". That will give you the type you need to specify here:

```
const handleSubmit: ${Type} = data => {
    // Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.
  };

  const { submitHandler, register } = useForm({ handleSubmit });
```

Comment: Yeah.. So that means I have no other alternative other that just importing the Interface along with the useForm hook, correct? Idk why, just felt bad to need to import that Interface when the type is available in the first example...